# Codeigniter - count an array from the database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code:

```
$product = $this->basic->get_data('products_imported',array('where'=>array('product_table'=>$product_table,'company_id' =>$company_id)));
```

As you can see the result is an `array()`.
So if I want to fetch the first result I have to use this:

```
$first_product = isset($product [0]['id']) ? $product [0]['id'] : 'empty';
```

How can I count all the results? I have to output the results like this:

```
count all products = 10 // for example
first_product = 3 // the product id
```

I tried `num_rows` and I have this error:

> Message: Attempt to read property "num_rows" on array

I also tried like this:

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('products_imported');
$this->db->where(['product_table' => $product_table, 'company_id'=>$company_id]);
$products_counter = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

For this code, I can count the results, but I can't fetch the first product like before in the first code.

Comment: You can use `count($product)` to count the number of elements in the array.

Comment: have a look at the docs ["Generating Query Results - Result rows"](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html?highlight=first_row#result-rows), there is an explanation how to move through a dataset with `$row = $query->first_row()`or `$row = $query->first_row('array')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fetch the first row because you haven't fetched anything.
You are using `$this->db->count_all_results()` which does not return an object.
It's also a reason why `$this->db->num_rows();` returns nothing the results after a count is zero.

Change

```
$products_counter = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

to

```
$query = $this->db->get();
$product = $query->result_array();
$products_counter = count($product);
```

And you get the `$product[0]['id']` you are looking for as well